# iPhone and embedded Google calendar not showing

Tags: iphone, wordpress, google-chrome, calendar, widget

I have a website run using wordpress (please no snarky comments about it) that features two different Google calendars embedded in widgets. They always worked fine until a few months ago when I noticed on my iphone (iphone XS) that the calendars do not appear. I have tried to replicate the problem on my computer by trying different window sizes, but the calendar always appears. Any suggestions on how I can tackle this weird problem or any ideas what might be going on. [Here's the calendar on the computer with the narrow window] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJOBI.png)

So one key problem is that the website isn't working well using the safari browser in general. As you can see here, the calendar isn't present even when the website is full sized. On Chrome I do not have this problem and the calendar is visible. I have noticed it disappearing from my phone as well. I have not been able to test the calendar on other devices.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VYSr.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJOBI.png)